# How do I open a modal/ dialog from a button from nav bar component in every page react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-component

when I click the icon from the topnav component to open modal ,the modal does not open but "modal open" text is console logged . The Top nav component has a fixed height in the main page.
I need to be able to open this modal in every page that's why I added it to Nav-bar .

Topnav component

```
export default function Topnav({ page }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="top-nav">
        <icon className='btn' onClick={() => {setShow(!show)}}>
          <VscOrganization size={20} />
        </icon>
      <h4 className="title">{page}</h4>
      
     <Modal show={show}/>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

modal

```
function Modal({ show }) {
  const classes= useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(show);
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper + " modal"}>
          <div>
            this is the modal text
            {console.log('modal open')}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two states for opening and closing, you need just one in the `Topnav` component.

Here is what I mean:

Topnav component: add onClose to the modal

```js
export default function Topnav({ page }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="top-nav">
        <icon className='btn' onClick={() => {setShow(true)}}>
          <VscOrganization size={20} />
        </icon>
      <h4 className="title">{page}</h4>
      
     <Modal show={show} onClose={() => setShow(false)}/>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

modal: remove the `open` state and just use the props

```js
function Modal({ show, onClose }) {
  const classes= useStyles();
  const [modalStyle] = useState(getModalStyle);

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal open={show} onClose={onClose}>
        <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper + " modal"}>
          <div>
            this is the modal text
            {console.log('modal open')}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did this , now the whole screen becomes grey like a modal background , but the modal still doesn't show

Comment: Can you make sure that your modal is not taking the whole screen? make sure your styles are correct and loaded correctly. Because it looks like the modal is loaded correctly and it is covering everything else.

Comment: the styles are default one's from material ui